# Improting google_play_services in ADT

Tags: android, android-activity, android-mapview, android-resources, android-package-managers

When i import the google_play_services_lib package it shows me error in my res-->values folder. There are many folder starting with values and the error exists in most of those folders. I have downloaded all the SDK from SDK manager including Obsolete for API 9. Can you plz help me with this so that I will be able to continue my programming on map view and adding ad packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do quite a bit of stuff to get your map going.
First you have to include google_play_services in your eclipse workspace. From properties/Android you should check Is Library check box.
Then you should add it as a reference in your own app. Right click/properties/Android/Add
and you choose the google play services project. As long as it comes to including the play_services, you should be done. For more, refer to http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: I tried this and now it shows me the following error [2014-07-30 08:36:06 - Test2] C:\Users\Matdroid\workspace\google-play-services_lib\res\values-zu\strings.xml:29: error: Resource entry auth_client_requested_by_msg is already defined.
[2014-07-30 08:36:06 - Test2] C:\Users\Matdroid\workspace\google-play-services_lib\res\values-zu\auth_strings.xml:9: Originally defined here.
My R.java file has got deleted. The error still exists in imported google_play_services in my workspace and also in my project.

Comment: Try starting over. It seems that some dependencies got mixed up. Delete the play_services project, unlink yours from it and do a clean of everything. Then start again.